# compress file with Java ByteArrayOutputstream

Tags: java, compression, bytearrayoutputstream

I am trying to compress file with Java ByteArrayOutputstream,but I failed.If I change the ouputstream to FileOutput stream,it can work.What should I do to make it work?and why?

Here is my code(Sorrry,my english is so poor):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class ZipOutputStreamTest {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    test1();
    test2();
}

/*this failed, the exported file can't be open*/
public static void test1() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = genZip(baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("d:\\test1.zip"), bytes);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:\\test1.zip"));
    for(byte b : bytes){
        fos.write(b);
    }
    fos.close();
    zos.close();
    baos.close();
}

/*this can work*/
public static void test2() throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("d:\\test2.zip");
    ZipOutputStream zos = genZip(fileOutputStream);
    zos.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}

public static ZipOutputStream genZip(OutputStream os) throws IOException{
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os, Charset.forName("gbk"));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("ab"+i+".txt");
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write("中文asaf".getBytes());
        zos.closeEntry();
        }
        return zos;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using FileOutputStream together with FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(...)? You write same data twice.

Remove FileOutputStream usage in test1(). Something like this:

```
public static void test1() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = genZip(baos);
    zos.close();
    baos.close();

    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("d:\\test1.zip"), bytes);
}
```

Comment: Tanks for your help.I have remove the FileOutputStream in test1(),but it is still not work.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I launched code on my computer and got expected results: http://i.imgur.com/h6dQonL.png

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue.. It got resolved when I added 
zos.finish();