# How can I put 2 ByteArrayOutputStreams into a zip file for download?

Tags: java, zip, bytearrayoutputstream

I was trying to generate 2 PDF data and put it inside a ZIP file for download (through response.getOutputStream) but I don't have idea how to do it properly:

```
public void export() {
    String fileName = "B2B_Price_List.zip";
    String fileNameUSD = "B2B_Price_List_USD.pdf";
    String fileNameEU = "B2B_Price_List_EU.pdf";

    String contentTypePDF = "application/pdf";
    String[] headerPDF = new String[2];
    headerPDF[0] = "Content-disposition";
    headerPDF[1] = "attachment; filename=\"" +  fileNameUSD + "\"";
    headerPDF[2] = "attachment; filename=\"" +  fileNameEU + "\"";

    String contentTypeZIP = "application/zip";
    String[] headerZIP = new String[1];
    headerZIP[0] = "Content-disposition";
    headerZIP[1] = "attachment; filename=\"" +  fileName + "\"";

    ByteArrayOutputStream outUSD = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outUSD = CSVHandler.downloadPriceListPDF(outUSD, fileNameUSD, ListToPDFMap(productsUSD), true);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outEU = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outEU = CSVHandler.downloadPriceListPDF(outEU, fileNameEU, ListToPDFMap(productsEU), false);
    // ZIP CODING GOES HERE
}
```

This function returns ByteArrayOutputStream to be used later:

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream downloadPriceListPDF
    (ByteArrayOutputStream output, final String filename,
     Map<String, Map<String, List<B2BProductData>>> datas,
     boolean amerCustomer) {
    try {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = null;
        try {
            pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(output));    

            PageSize pageSize = new PageSize(PageSize.A4);
            Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, pageSize, false);
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());

            String coverImage = COVER_IMAGE;
            if(!amerCustomer) {
                coverImage = COVER_IMAGE_1;
            }

            canvas.addImage(ImageDataFactory.create(CSVHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResource(coverImage).getPath()), pageSize, false);

            // loop thru category
            int pageNo = 2;
            Map<String, List<B2BProductData>> inputDatas = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for(String category : datas.keySet()) {
                Map<String, List<B2BProductData>> prods = datas.get(category);

                while(true) {
                    inputDatas = new LinkedHashMap<>();                 
                    Map<String, List<B2BProductData>> remaindatas = filterDatas(inputDatas, prods);

                    if(inputDatas.size() > 0) {
                        createPDFPage(pdfDoc, doc, category, inputDatas, pageNo ++, amerCustomer);
                    }

                    if(remaindatas.size() > 0) {
                        prods =  remaindatas;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }           

            doc.close();

            return output;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            return output;
        }
    }
    catch (final Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Export Products got error: " + ex.getMessage());
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably also want to edit your question to remove your iText tags and iText code because your question is about zip only and it doesn’t really matter what you pass to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compress file with Java ByteArrayOutputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482779/compress-file-with-java-bytearrayoutputstream)

Comment: Agreed, change your title and tags to attract more viewers who may be able to help.

Comment: @Sorifiend The answer I seek is quite different from the one in the link. I answered my own question anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I made it like this:

Declared the Filenames to be used later.

```
                String fileName = "B2B_Price_List.zip";
                String fileNameUSD = "B2B_Price_List_USD.pdf";
                String fileNameEU = "B2B_Price_List_EU.pdf";
```

Declare a new ByteArrawOutputStream class and initialize with "new".

```
                ByteArrayOutputStream outUSD = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream outEU = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

After generating a PDF file, return the value ByteArrayOutputStream and assign to the ByteArrayStream declared earlier.

```
                if (hasUSD) outUSD = CSVHandler.generatePriceListPDF(outUSD, ListToPDFMap(productsUSD), true, true);
                if (hasEU) outEU = CSVHandler.generatePriceListPDF(outEU, ListToPDFMap(productsEU), false, true);
```

Declare an outputstream to be used to hold **response** object's OutputStream.

```
                OutputStream responseOutputStream;
```

Declare the header strings to be assigned to the **response** object's header data. In this case the MIME type would be **application/zip** for zip file. The **fileName** (*B2B_Price_List.zip*) is also used to define the download's filename.

```
                    String contentTypeZIP = "application/zip";
                    String[] headerZIP = new String[1];
                    headerZIP[0] = "Content-disposition";
                    headerZIP[1] = "attachment; filename=\"" +  fileName + "\"";
```

Set the **response** object's headers.

```
                    response.setContentType(contentTypeZIP);
                    response.setHeader(headerZIP[0], headerZIP[1]);
```

Set the responseOutputStream to hold the **response** object's outputstream.

```
                    responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
```

Declare a **ZipOutputStream** and initialize **new** with the response's outputstream as a parameter. The parameter will be used to write to write here the file to be downloaded later, in this case, the ZIP file.

```
                    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(responseOutputStream);
```

Declare the **ZipEntry** objects to be put inside the ZIP file. Initialize **new** with the filename string as a parameter. In this case, we'll put **2** files inside the ZIP file for example.

```
                    ZipEntry zipEntryUSD = new ZipEntry(fileNameUSD);
                    ZipEntry zipEntryEU = new ZipEntry(fileNameEU);
```

Put each entries (or files) one at a time, after the **putNextEntry** is called for an entry, it is then assumed that the next **.write** called will be written to the previously **put** entry.

In this case we called the **.write** with the **ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()** to convert to *ByteArray* as a parameter. Don't forget to close the entry by calling **.closeEntry()**, then proceed to the next file(s) with the same procedure earlier.

```
                    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntryUSD);
                    zos.write(outUSD.toByteArray());
                    zos.closeEntry();

                    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntryEU);
                    zos.write(outEU.toByteArray());
                    zos.closeEntry();
```

After writing the entries (files) you needed inside the ZIP, don't forget to close the **ZipOutputStream** (*zos* in this case).

```
                    zos.close();
```

The file will then proceed for download after you **flush** / **close** the **response**'s output stream. You may ignore **flush** but to be sure, I included it anyway.

```
                    responseOutputStream.flush();
                    responseOutputStream.close();
```

**END OF CODE BLOCK**

---

**CSVHandler.generatePriceListPDF**

Now this is the function used to generate **PDF** > to > **ByteArrayOutputStream**. We passed the **output** object ByteArrayOutputStream from earlier to be re-assigned to the passed ByteArrayOutputStream object outside this function.

example:

*outUSD = CSVHandler.generatePriceListPDF(outUSD, ListToPDFMap(productsUSD), true, true);*

**FUNCTION BLOCK START**

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream downloadPriceListPDF
    (ByteArrayOutputStream output, final String filename,
     Map<String, Map<String, List<B2BProductData>>> datas,
     boolean amerCustomer, boolean autoCloseByteArrayOutputStream) {
    try {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = null;
        try {
```

Initialize **writer** as new PdfWriter with the ByteArrayOutputStream as a parameter, in this case the *output* object from the function parameter.

```
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(output);
```

Initialize **pdfDoc** as new PdfDocument with the PdfWriter object *writer* in this case as parameter. This instructs the pdfDoc to write directly to the ByteArrayOutputStream (*output*) object

```
            pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
```

Initialize PDF document parameters such as sizes and such.

```
            PageSize pageSize = new PageSize(PageSize.A4);
            Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, pageSize, false);
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());
```

This is the part where you write your PDF, with data, images or anything up to you.

```
            // YOUR OWN PDF WRITE OPERATION HERE
```

Don't forget to close your PDF Document after you finish writing stuff.

```
            doc.close();
```

The function parameter **autoCloseByteArrayOutputStream** boolean I added determines if you want to close the ByteArrayOutputStream inside this function, or close it outside if you want to supplement the content outside. Your choice, but don't forget to **close ByteArrayOutputStream** all the time anyway.

```
        If (autoCloseByteArrayOutputStream) {
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        }
```

Return the *output* **ByteArrayOutputStream**.

```
            return output;
        } catch (IOException e) {
```

If an exception occur, it's important to return an object on all code paths. In this case we return a *null* value **ByteArrayOutputStream** in an event of error.

```
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            return output;
        }
    }
    catch (final Exception ex) {
```

Same here, errors return *null* **ByteArrayOutputStream** in case of error.

```
        LOG.error("Export Products got error: " + ex.getMessage());
        return output;
    }
}
```

**END OF FUNCTION BLOCK**

Comment: Please add some explanations to your answer

Comment: At your service.